# Dynamically linking to a Facebook Company Page

Tags: facebook

Our database has an entry for our companies' Facebook and Twitter pages. With Twitter, it's possible to create dynamic links based solely on the company's Twitter handler. For instance, if the company provides us with the Twitter handle `acme`, we can dynamically create a link to their Twitter page with `<a href='http://www.twitter.com/#{company.twitter_name}'></a>`.

In some instances, the same is true of Facebook. Coca Cola for instance has `http://www.facebook.com/cocacola`. Many other companies have a url that looks more like `http://www.facebook.com/pages/acme/123456789`. In the latter case, the numerical id at the end is necessary to reach the page. The URL `http://www.facebook.com/pages/acme` would not work.

My question is, is there a way to dynamically link to a Facebook company page with just their handle? Or do you always need to provide a full URL? I'm hoping Facebook has some magic back door for developers that I simply haven't happened upon yet. Thanks for your feedback, one way or the other!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A link in the form `http(s)://facebook.com/profile.php?id={nummeric_id_here}` always works, for pages as well as for user profiles.

It automatically redirects to the “real” address – to the username that the user or page might have set, or to an address in the form you mentioned (for pages that do not have enough likes yet to set their own user name).

Comment: This works great. What about in an instance where we do not have access to the company's numeric id, as with Coca Cola? (Their id isn't in their standard url.) Is there a way to publicly find their numeric id, or has that become private?

Comment: Actually, it looks like I just found an [answer](http://xenforo.com/help/facebook-user-id/). Thanks again, CBroe!